# Expressjs CSRF protection

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, csrf

i'm implementing csurf middlware to prevent CSRF attacks. I don't understand why I've to store the token generated in a cookie:

```
csurf({ cookie: {
    sameSite: true,
    httpOnly: true
}})
```

when I can render the value in a hidden input and then receive it back in the payload of the POST request.

```
res.render("registration", {csrfToken: req.csrfToken()});
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{csrfToken}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

The cookie usage allows you to use CSRF for JavaScript implementations (i.e. if you're using React or Angular or Vue you can read the CSRF value out of the cookie and send it back as a request parameter or header).

Comment: thanks for the response... so i couldn't use the cookie if the middleware checks on the payload

Comment: The middleware typically looks in a number of places (see https://github.com/expressjs/csurf/blob/master/index.js#L130). With same-site protection in place the cookie is the easiest thing to use, but including it in the post body works too.